# Unable to run executable from mounted flashdrive on Chromebook

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, chroot, chromebook

I recently got a Chromebook and installed Crouton on it so I can run Ubuntu natively. Since the machine only has 16GB of SSD I decided to get a tiny flash drive that I can keep in it at all times. The problem is that when I try to execute files that are in fact executable, they either don't run (using sudo) or say permission denied (sans sudo).

I am testing using a simple hello world C program, which works if I execute it from the Desktop.

```
user@localhost: ~/USB
$  gcc -o hello hello.c
user@localhost: ~/USB
$  ls -l
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 7798 Oct 23 11:38 hello
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  114 Oct 23 11:03 hello.c
user@localhost: ~/USB
$  ./hello
bash: ./hello: Permission denied
user@localhost: ~/USB
$  sudo ./hello
[sudo] password for user: 
user@localhost: ~/USB
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file permissions allow execution, check the mount options, and ensure that the USB device does NOT have the noexe set, preventing execution.  Type mount, and check the device options.  They are usually being set in the file /etc/fstab.  Remove the unwanted options there.
    ****
Look to the Chrome OS side, since the Ubuntu fstab doesn't look like it is in use.  Don't know about Chrome OS, but Gnome also can be a source of mounts (typically putting them under /media...

Comment: As you predicted the USB drive in question has noexe set, however in the /etc/fstab file there is only one line that says: #UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM. Any ideas on how to unset noexe? Thanks for the quick response btw